# How can I get what I'm reading in from a file to an output file

Tags: java

I'm able to pull out the 20 names randomly but how do I store them in an output file rather than displaying them to the screen? I tried filewriter but couldn't get it to work.

```
public class Assignment2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Read in the file into a list of strings
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("textfile.txt"));
        //BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("out.txt"));
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

        String line = reader.readLine();

        while( line != null ) {
            lines.add(line);
            line = reader.readLine();
        }

        // Choose a random one from the list
        Random r = new Random();
        FileWriter letters = new FileWriter("out.txt");
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            int rowNum = r.nextInt(lines.size ());
            System.out.println(lines.get(rowNum));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Filewrite.write(lines.get(rowNum))`?

Comment: You need to write to `letters`, not `System.out`.

Comment: I tried the first one but did not work and i know i need to write letters but confused how to. the System.out is just so i know it is working

Answer (score 0):

I am using a convince method to write to the file from the library `commons.io-2.4`, code is also available on [github](https://github.com/pankajnimgade/JavaCoding_tutorials/blob/master/src/stack/overflow/test/first/WriteFile.java)

this example demonstrate how to `read` and `write` `String` lines to a `file`

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Pankaj Nimgade on 10-02-2016.
 */
public class WriteFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            list.add("somename_" + i);
        }

        File file = new File("file.txt");
        try {
//            FileUtils.writeLines(file, list);

            ArrayList<String> strings = (ArrayList<String>) FileUtils.readLines(file);

           ArrayList<Name> names = new ArrayList<>();

            for (String single:strings) {
                names.add(new Name(single));
                if (names.size() == 20) {
                   break;
                }
            }

            for (Name single_name:names) {
                System.out.println(single_name.getName());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}

class Name {

    String name;

    public Name(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return this.name.equalsIgnoreCase(((Name) obj).getName());
    }
}
```

> output, this will be inside file.txt

```
somename_0
somename_1
somename_2
somename_3
somename_4
somename_5
somename_6
somename_7
somename_8
somename_9
somename_10
somename_11
somename_12
somename_13
somename_14
somename_15
somename_16
somename_17
somename_18
somename_19
```

Comment: I'm new to java and don't understand the import for the FileUtils

Comment: @CorDell ok, there are many libraries made by other developer which can be used to do some task you want to perform. https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/   ..
is one of the library provided by apache that can be ulilized to do some work related to input/output, this library has some methods that can be used to do the task you want..
so download the jar file of the library and add it project as library and run this code, I have also provided the like to the github, where you can check the code

Comment: @CorDell , FileUtils class belongs to a library which you would have to add as library to your project to be able to call it in your code

Comment: Alright thanks, just struggling on figuring out which is the right one to download

Comment: download it from here https://github.com/pankajnimgade/JavaCoding_tutorials/blob/master/libs/commons-io-2.4.jar  or pass me your email address i will mail it to you

Comment: it's ok, everyone-one has to go through the first time

Comment: Thank you i appreciate all the help. Never knew about libraries

Comment: Now im trying to use this to read in exactly 20 different names from the file each time but it is giving me all the names. How can i change this?

Comment: it is happening because it reads everything in the file, what you can do is make your own class type which makes sure it does not same string

Comment: The fileutils is? or is it something im doing?

Comment: @CorDell, FileUtils will read the lines as they are, you would have to filter them on your own, what i am suggesting is, make a class which will override equals method and compare the name so you will always get a unique name for that type of arraylist

Comment: @CorDell , i have updated the answer, check how it works, it will only save unique name in the list

Comment: i have also uploaded the code to github so you can check it

Comment: It is still reading all the names from the file.. instead of putting them in myself im reading them form a file

Comment: i have updated the answer, first you have to read the file and you will get all duplicate names in it, after this make another arrayList of type Name and add all the names to this list and you will get the unique names @CorDell

Comment: the library does the low level code for you @CorDell, so you need not worry about file reader

Comment: So is the output your displaying being read from a file? because it looks like your making the info in the code with   for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                                                                   list.add("somename_" + i);

Comment: @CorDell yes you are right, if you want you can skip the writing the file and replace the file content with the content you want it to be there and run the cade

Comment: Ive been changing things to figure it out. But i cant seem to figure out how to take your code and make it read in 20 different names from the file each time and put them in a output file. It HAS to be read in from a file

Comment: @CorDell well even if you read the entire file you can just make ArrayList<Name> have only first 20 unique name and then skip adding any new name to it as it reaches the count of 20

Comment: Thats the problem im confused on how to set this up to do that

Comment: if (names.size() == 20) {
                    break;
                } put this line after every time you add names to the arrayList

Answer (score 0):

`System.out` is a `PrintStream` ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html)) and not a `Writer` ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html)) so the api to access it will be different, you can't replace one by the other.  The `Writer` is some how a lower level abstraction.

But it is easy to create a `PrintStream` that output a a file and use it as replacement of `System.out`:

```
PrintStreasm out = new PrintStream("out.txt");
// you can event assign System.out to out.
// out = System.out;
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      int rowNum = r.nextInt(lines.size ());
      out.println(lines.get(rowNum));
}
out.close()
```

PS: don't forget to closed any file you open (auto closable functionality of Java 7 is even better)
PSS: I assume you are learning Java, I can't recommend enough that you have a look to at the [Java I/O stream apis](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/streams.html).

Comment: This still only displays 20 on the screen. It isn't adding anything to my out.txt file

Comment: Then you are calling the `println` on System.out and not on the `PrintStream` you have created.